# How to map all requests to single controller method in spring?

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

I am new to spring. I want to map all the requests to single controller method. That's why I have specified following requestmapping

```
@RequestMapping
(
  value="/PnPanel.go/CData/**", 
  method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}
)
```

But still it's giving 404 error, when URL is requested

```
http://localhost:8088/PnPanel.go/CData/invokeCDScreen
```

Don't know, what I am missing here.
I tried searching on net, but all the solutions didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _http://{hostname}:{port}/{war-name}/{controller-mapping}_ . _http://localhost:8088/PnPanel.go/CData/invokeCDScreen_ will work if your war name is _ROOT.war_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I had solved it myself. I was missing the following thing :-

```
@RequestMapping
(
  value="/PnPanel.go/CData/*", 
  method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}
)
```

Thus, instead of using two asterisks, only one was required.

Answer (score 3):

Your `URL` should be `http://localhost:8088/<project-name>/PnPanel.go/CData/invokeCDScreen` to match the request mapping.